# codeigniter upload image and insert path into database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys i am trying to upload image in to uploads folder and insert that path into the database when i tried noting is happening.i don't know what is the exact problem when i upload the image it is  showing upload image name in URL. like this

```
http://localhost/pes/Content/editContent?details=download.jpg&uploadimg=upload
```

Here is my controller:

```
function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '';
    $config['max_height'] = '';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->Content_model->insert_images($this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('content/content', $error);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {
        $this->Content_model->insert_images($this->upload->data());
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('content/editdescription', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
function insert_images($image_data = array()){
  $data = array(
      'details' => $image_data['details']
   );
  $this->db->insert('contentdetails', $data);
 }
```

Here is my view:

```
<form>
                    <?php echo form_open_multipart('Content/do_upload'); ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="file" name="details" size="20" multiple="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <button type="submit"  name="uploadimg" value="upload" class="form-control btn btn-main">Upload File</button>

                </form>
```

Can any one help me what mistake i have done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: echo the `$error` var in your view. what does it say? or echo it in your controller

Comment: yeah when i use echo $error it is showing undefined variable $error

Comment: <?php echo $error;?> if i pass like this its giving me error(Undefined variable: error) can you please tell me how can i pass?

Comment: then you must be entering the 2nd condition where error isn't defined which is bad design. but you are aware that 1) codeigniter doesn't out of the box support multiple images in one upload right 2) `$image_data['details']` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: no its not defined

Comment: these are the available variable "keys": https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data

Comment: when i upload the file it is showing error "You did not select a file to upload".

Comment: please read the docs. it is there for a reason. here is a hint: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::do_upload

Comment: i have changed few things but still i am getting same error..can you please help me where i have done mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176692/discussion-between-alex-and-suresh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; // make folder if doesn't exist; ci won't do this for you
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '';
    $config['max_height'] = '';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $data['error'] = '';

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('details')) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        // an error occurred, why would you want to insert nothing?
        //$this->Content_model->insert_images($this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('content/content', $data); // echo $error in view
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    } else {
        $this->Content_model->insert_images($this->upload->data());
        $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('content/editdescription', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}


function insert_images($image_data = array()){
  $data = array(
      'details' => $image_data['full_path']
   );
  $this->db->insert('contentdetails', $data);
 }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="details" size="20" />
```

Remove:

```
<form>
```

Multiple files: https://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+multiple+file+upload&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS777US777&oq=CODEIGNITER+MULTI&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.2783j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: i have already uploads folder in my xampp/ htdocs/pes/uploads

Comment: there was one more change.... `./uploads/` notice the dot... same as in the examples in the docs...

Comment: yes i have used ./uploads/ like that but still gettign same error

Comment: because `./` refers to your doc root which is `xampp/htdocs` ... so if you want it to be `pes/uploads` you have to write `./pes/uploads/` or just make a folder in your doc root called uploads which would be  the htdocs folder

Comment: i have used like this $config['upload_path'] = './pes/uploads/'; but still getting same error

Comment: go here:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176692/discussion-between-alex-and-suresh

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
<form>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Content/do_upload'); ?>
```

it is creating two different forms, one by html tag and another one by CI html form helper. So remove the outer one and try again.

[Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: getting this error: The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: Check the path you are using, that exist and have file write permission

Comment: hi i have created new folder and gave full permission but still getting same problem

Comment: @hi i ahve one doubt may i ask

Comment: Yes, go ahead and ask.

Comment: can you please come to this chat